# System.Data.SQLite.dllを参照追加しようとするとエラーになる

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

C#でSQLiteを触るためにWindowsストアアプリの空のアプリケーション(Windows)を選択し、
System.Data.SQLite.dllを参照追加しようとすると次のエラーメッセージが表示されます。

> 'c:\Users\nhs30233\Documents\Visual Stadio 2013\Projects\SQLiteDLL\System.Data.SQlite.dll'への参照を追加できませんでした。プロジェクトは'.NETCore'を対象としていますが、ファイル参照は'.NETFramework'を対象としています。これはサポートされないシナリオです。

環境は 
・windows8.1 
・x64 
・visual studio 2013 
です。

System.Data.SQLite.dllは、 
Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.6) の 
sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x64-2015-1.0.98.0.exe を落としてインストールしました。

visual studio 2013\Project\の中に作ったプロジェクトがあり、 
そこにdllファイルを置いたり、参照追加するプロジェクトのフォルダの中に置いたりと 
いろいろ試しましたが結果は変わりませんでした。

.NETFrameworkはどれがPCに入っているのか分からなかったので、 
プログラムのアンインストールの場所で確認したところ4.5~4.6までありました。

.NETCoreはMacやLinuxでも.NETFrameworkが使えるようにしたもの 
という事は分かりました。

つまり、プロジェクトとSystem.Data.SQLite.dllの、 
いわゆるバージョン的なイメージのものが合っていないから参照できないよと 
言われているのかと考えています。

しかし対処法は全く分からなかった為、質問させて頂きました。

調べた結果はすべて英語のページで読めませんでしたし、 
翻訳サイトで翻訳してみても意味が分かりませんでした。

どう対処したらよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 表示されたエラーメッセージは一字一句正しいものでしょうか？ 一般的には「だが」などという表現は使われませんが…。
また質問文には追加しようとしたアセンブリは記載されていますが、追加先となるプロジェクトについての言及がありません。その部分を明確にしないとエラーを解消できないと思われます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windowsストアアプリを本当に作成したいのかが疑問です。他のプロジェクト形式を選択すべきではないかを再度確認することをお勧めします。（他のプロジェクト形式であればsqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x64-2015-1.0.98.0.exeのインストールで動作します。）

> 調べた結果はすべて英語のページで読めませんでしたし、 
>   翻訳サイトで翻訳してみても意味が分かりませんでした。

このようにダウンロードサイトも英語です。ソフトウェア開発を行う前に最低限の英語を読めるようになるべきです。

---

[ストアアプリ用.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx)は通常の.NET Frameworkのサブセットであり、データベースを扱うSystem.Data名前空間は含まれていません。ですので、.NET Framework向けのデータベース関する情報はストアアプリにおいては一切役に立たないとお考え下さい。

[SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1)](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d04f82f-2fe9-4727-a2f9-a2db127ddc9a)はC/C++言語用のライブラリであり、sqlite3.h、sqlite3.lib、sqlite3.dllを提供するものでした。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
参照の追加の拡張からSQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1)をインストールし、追加していましたが動きませんでした。
リンク先から行う必要があるのでしょうか。試してみます。
また、保存先はどこにしたら良いのでしょうか？
英語のサイトも見ながらですが、プロジェクト名のフォルダ\bin\Debugの中に入れるのでしょうか。

作成したい物はWindowsストアアプリです。
恐らくWindowsFormApplicationを選ぶべきだと仰りたいのではないかと思うのですが、xamlで開発することが前提であります。
そうなるとプロジェクト形式はWindowsストアアプリの空のアプリケーション(Windows)になると思っています。
自分の知識不足もありますので、プロジェクト形式についても調べてみます。

Comment: xamlをサポートするのはWindowsストアアプリの他にWPFアプリケーションもあります。前者はWindows8のみで7以前や10では動作しません。後者はxp以降すべてのバージョンで動作します。本当にストアアプリを作成したいのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
WPFアプリケーションについて調べてみます。

ストアアプリを作成したいのかという問いの意図が分かりません。
私の気持ちを答えれば良いのか、本当はストアアプリではなく別の何かを作成するつもりではないのかとお考えなのか。
私の気持ちとしては作りたいと思っています。
それは私の経験となり将来の武器になると考えているからです。
なぜストアアプリなのかと言われれば、ストアアプリで使用するDB関連の動きをSQLiteで作成してほしいと言われたからです。私個人に対して頼まれたのであればやったことがないと言ってしまえますが、詳しくはお話しできませんが立場上断ることが出来ません。また、前述した通り、挑戦する気持ちを持っているので、自分に無い新しい技術に触れる良いきっかけになっていると考えています。
後者についてですが、Windowsストアアプリの空のアプリケーション(Windows)でsqliteを使用することで何か法的に、もしくは世間など人様に危害を加えられるような物が作られる可能性があるとお考えなのでしょうか？結論から言ってしまえばそのようなことは一切考えておりません。もしかしたら見当違いな事を言っているのかもしれませんが。私が今回ストアアプリを作成する理由はスキルアップ以外にはありません。

Comment: 昨晩寝る前にこの件について調べていたのですが、[Using SQLite in Windows 8 Store Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2012/11/13/using-sqlite-in-windows-store-apps.aspx)というページを見つけました。しかしこのページも英語です。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
頑張って読んでみます。
英語の勉強もしなければいけませんね。

Comment: sayuriさん追記ありがとうございます。
様々なサイトで言っていることやっていることが違いすぎて分からなくなってしまいました。
つまり、System.Data.SQLite.dllを使用する場合はソースの最初にusingでSystem.Data.SQLite;を宣言(?)する事は出来ないという事なのでしょうか。

SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1)については、sqlite3.dllを使用するのでソースの最初にusingでSystem.Data.SQLite;を宣言(?)するということなのでしょうか。そして、SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1)をインストールすればsqlite3.dllも手に入るという事なのでしょうか。

sqlite3.dllはコマンドラインからではなくPHPなどのアプリケーションから利用され、System.Data.SQLite.dllは.NET環境で利用できるという情報がありますが、この.NET環境とは.NET Framework向けのデータベース関する情報であり、ストアアプリ用.NETのことではないのでしょうか？http://c-loft.com/blog/?p=1497

Comment: @mahuyu `System.Data.SQLite.dll`は.NET Frameworkでは利用できますが、ストアアプリでは利用できません。挙げられたブログ記事はストアアプリ登場以前に書かれたもののようです（記事は2012/1/7に書かれていますが、ストアアプリ対応のVisual Studio 2012は2012/9/12公開です）。読む前にドキュメントが何を対象としているか確認することをお勧めします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
System.Data.SQLite.dllがずっと追加出来なかったので、ストアアプリでは利用できないという情報はとてもありがたいです。
ドキュメントの対象の確認も意識して情報収集をしていきたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

nuget経由で導入すると適切に配置してくれます。


`Install-Package System.Data.SQLite`

Entity Flameworkなどを入れたくない場合は、Coreを選択する(SQLiteのみ)

`Install-Package System.Data.SQLite.Core`

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
NuGetのパッケージ管理のオンラインで、System.Data.SQLite(x86,x64)をインストールするという事だと思うのですが、それだけですとコードの方でusing System.Data.SQLite;の部分がエラーになった記憶があります。「'Data'は'System'に存在しない」といった内容でした。他に何かすべきなのでしょうか？既に15時間近く情報を集めていますが見つからないので、よろしければご教授願います。

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html から"Precompiled Binaries for Windows Runtime"をインストールします。
次に参照から"SQLite for Windows Runtime"を追加します。
※Any CPUは、使用できません。x86,x64,APMの何れかを選択する必要があります。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
Precompiled Binaries for Windows Runtimeのインストール→
SQLite for Windows RuntimeとMicrosoft Visual C++ Runtime Packageを追加→sqlite-netのインストール→ソースコードにusing System.Data.SQLite;を記述の流れで間違い、漏れはなかったでしょうか？